# Why is my Settings.bundle empty?

Tags: xcode4

I'm teaching myself iOS programming and am trying to add a Settings Bundle Resource to my Hello World app, following instructions in the iOS Application Programming Guide. The Settings.bundle object is created in my project (with the disclosure triangle) but there are no files inside.

I expected a Root.plist and en.lproj/Root.strings

Am I missing something in my Xcode4 installation or Xcode setup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you click on it with the mouse, and choose "Show in Finder", and in Finder click on it and choose "Show Package Contents", you'll see that it's a directory.

(I found the answer at http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/92361-settings-bundle-corrupted-newly-added-settings-bundle-also-bad-xcode-4-2-a.html )

[quote]

Click on the Settings.bundle file in the left window; from main menu choose *View* -> *Utilities* -> *Show FileInspector*. Then change fileType to "applicationBundle" -- the two missing files will show under Settings.bundle.

[/quote]

(FileInspector is the right column (to the right from the central view(s)), the tab with an icon showing a page with a paper-clip in the corner)

Comment: Hmm, I wish the problem still existed (newer versions of Xcode have remedied the issue) so I could test out your suggestion -- sounds very promising!

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, this was fixed in a newer version of Xcode. I'll remember to include versions numbers next time.